# Applying a monthly level loss factor in the hourly time series using Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time-series

I have a following hourly time series consisting of 2 years in a dataframe (df)

`date          energy
1/1/1997 0:00     37
1/1/1997 1:00     44
1/1/1997 2:00     55
.
.
.
12/31/1997 22:00  54
12/31/1997 23:00  55
1/1/1998 0:00     35
1/1/1998 1:00     36
1/1/1998 2:00     37
.
.
.
12/31/1998 23:00  44`

I want to apply following monthly losses to the Energy column:

`Monthly Loss
1   3.6158136
2   5.3829265
3   4.4004292
4   4.1649284
5   5.9518338
6   4.5651714
7   6.1399174
8   5.9933625
9   6.4627925
10  6.2534558
11  3.3416914
12  4.5363111`

```
Expected Output
date            energy   new_energy
1/1/1997 0:00     37     35.66   # 37 * (1-3.6158136/100)
1/1/1997 1:00     44     42.41   # 44 * (1-3.6158136/100) 
1/1/1997 2:00     55     53.01   # 55 * (1-3.6158136/100)
.
.
.
12/31/1997 22:00   54     51.55   # 54 * (1-4.5363111/100) 
12/31/1997 23:00   55     52.51   # 55 * (1-4.5363111/100) 
1/1/1998 0:00     35     33.73   # 35 * (1-3.6158136/100)
1/1/1998 1:00     36     34.70   # 36 * (1-3.6158136/100)
1/1/1998 2:00     37     35.66   # 37 * (1-3.6158136/100)
.
.
.
12/31/1997 22:00   54    51.55   # 54 * (1-4.5363111/100)
12/31/1997 23:00   55    52.50   # 55 * (1-4.5363111/100)
```

Below is my code. I am trying to find the easiest way to apply monthly loss to hourly time series

```
monthly_loss = [3.6158136, 5.3829265, 4.4004292, 4.1649284, 5.9518338, 4.5651714, 6.1399174, 5.9933625, 6.4627925, 6.2534558, 3.3416914, 4.5363111]

month = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.month

df.insert(2, 'Month', month)

# converting the energy from hourly to monthly level
df['monthly_resampled_data'] = df.energy.resample('M').mean()

# apply monthly loss by months to the energy values
df['new_energy']=df['monthly_resampled_data']*(1-monthly_loss/100)
```

Getting Error

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Comment: You cant unless what you want to apply to the energy column is monthly mean over the two years. If it is not, you should provide the year as well in the second dataframe. Because it is a two year period, it is possible to have month 1 in both Year 1 and Year 2 if you get what I mean. Maybe give us an example of expected outcome.

Comment: @wwnde I have added expected outcome to my question. I want all the monthly losses to be applied every year for that month from timestamp (meaning hour1 of January of 1997 and 1998 should apply the same loss of January to the energy values of hour 1 jan of 1997 and 1998). I wonder if there is a function in pandas that can do it easily.

Comment: That's better. See my attempt and let us know if it is what you wanted or not

Comment: Thanks! I like how you extracted month after converting data into datetime and then effectively used pd.merge to merge them!

Comment: In some cases, I will have losses in list data structures and not in a data frame so I am thinking of doing the following: `monthly_loss = [3.6158136, 5.3829265, 4.4004292, 4.1649284, 5.9518338, 4.5651714, 6.1399174, 5.9933625, 6.4627925, 6.2534558, 3.3416914, 4.5363111]         month = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]                                                                                            #converting lists into a dataframe                       df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(monthly_loss,  month)), columns = ['Monthly_Loss', 'Month'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coerce date to date time, set it as index and extract month in a column named Monthly

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index(df['date'], inplace=True)
df['Monthly']=df.index.month
```

Merge the two dataframes on column `Monthly`

```
df2= pd.merge(df, df1, on='Monthly', how='left')
```

Apply formula and drop unwanted columns

```
    df2['new_energy']=(df2['Energy']*(1-(df2['Loss']/100))).apply(lambda x:round(x,2))
df2.drop(columns=['Monthly','Loss'], inplace=True)
```

Output

[image]